# unable to start Activity after device restart

Tags: android

Unable to start Activity after device restart in Android 10

I am using BootComplete Broadcast receiver which is working perfectly but whenever I am starting activity in from receiver then activity doesn't get started

Even I started foreground service and then I tried to invoke activity from it but no luck.

```
   val activityIntent = Intent(this, SplashActivity::class.java)
    activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    startActivity(activityIntent)
```

Any solution, please?

Answer (score 2):

In Android 10 there are restrictions on starting activities from the background, read [Privacy changes in Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#background-activity-starts)